# How to get BLE Advertisement Data Swift 2

Tags: swift2, core-location, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

I am trying to scan near beacons and get info from them. Now i get some like uuid, major-minor values but i want t read advertisement data too. There is my code how can i handle it ?

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion)
    {
        // Tells the delegate that one or more beacons are in range.
        let foundBeacons = beacons
        if foundBeacons.count > 0 {       
            if let closestBeacon = foundBeacons[0] as? CLBeacon {
                var proximityMessage: String!
                    let makeString = "Beacon Details:\n"
                    let uuid = "UUID = \(closestBeacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString)\n"
                    let identifier = "Identifier = \(region.identifier)\n"
                    let major = "Major Value = \(closestBeacon.major.intValue)\n"
                    let minor = "Minor Value = \(closestBeacon.minor.intValue)\n"
                    let distance = "Distance From iBeacon = \(proximityMessage)"

                    self.beaconStatus.text = makeString
                    self.uuidStatus.text=uuid
                    self.distanceStatus.text=distance
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, **you cannot access raw advertisement data for iBeacon advertisements in iOS**.  Apple actively blocks access to the bluetooth advertisement data for any Bluetooth advertisement packet matching the iBeacon format.

This means the ProximityUUID, major and minor are all you can read.

See [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html) for more details.

Comment: This info really useful but i am confused. ın this sample i can read the advertisement data https://github.com/Ladvien/bleModule/blob/master/bleModule/bleTableViewController.swift
what is the difference how can i implement this on my code?

Comment: With that sample you can read advertisement data for non-iBeacon advertisements only

Comment: Ok than a last question how can i implement this function to read advertisement data for non-beacon advertisements